# Detect TOR network using the IP address

Tags: deanonymization, directory, ip-address, website

I have a website.

I just want to detect if the internet traffic is coming through TOR or not.

How to find If TOR is being used to access my website ?

Is there any catalog of IP address that belongs with TOR network ? so that I can cross check with that and ascertain TOR traffic or not.

Dhanyawath,

Raju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of Exit IP addresses is published by [CollecTor](https://collector.torproject.org/#exit-lists).

It is not, and never can be, 100% accurate, there is no way to ascertain certainly by IP address if the connection is coming from Tor.

Comment: is there any other way we can ascertain if connection is coming from Tor